# sqlalchemy error (sqlalchemy.exc.NoForeignKeysError)

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am playing with a toy example to see the back populates in action but hitting an error that I can't understand. Below I have two 'models' that back populate each other. When I try to create a User object it throws an error. What am I missing?

"sqlalchemy.exc.NoForeignKeysError: Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on relationship Child.user - there are no foreign keys linking these tables.  Ensure that referencing columns are associated with a ForeignKey or ForeignKeyConstraint, or specify a 'primaryjoin' expression."

```
  engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:', echo=False)
  Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
  session = Session()
  Base = declarative_base(bind=engine)

  class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    user_id = Column("UserID", Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column("Name", String(50))
    age = Column("Age", SmallInteger)
    child = relationship("Child", back_populates="user")

  class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'child'
    child_id = Column("ChildID", Integer, primary_key=True)
    school = Column("School", String)
    grade = Column("Grade", String)
    user_id = Column("UserID", Integer, ForeignKey('User.UserID'), index=True, nullable=True)
    user = relationship("User", back_populates="child")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ForeignKey` requires the table and column name, not model and attribute name, so it should be:

```
user_id = Column("UserID", Integer, ForeignKey('user.UserID'), ...)
```

because your `User` model has a table name of `user`.

Comment: @user3079275 Compare: [\[capital U\]](https://repl.it/JQs4) [\[lowercase u\]](https://repl.it/JQs4/1)

Comment: yes this is what I have:
user_id = Column("UserID", Integer, ForeignKey('user.UserID'), nullable=True)

Comment: In my OP it was 
user_id = Column("UserID", Integer, ForeignKey('User.UserID'), nullable=True)

Comment: @user3079275 I've basically copied your code verbatim and fixed it. If it doesn't work for you, then either your problem is unrelated to the code you've posted, or you're doing something different.